# Have to write a program that will average all of a numbers digits. And struggling where to start

Tags: python

So for my assignment I have  to start with these parameters.

"Write a program that will average all of a numbers digits.  You must use % for this lab to access the right most digit of the number.  You will use / to chop off the right most digit."

Now I'm kinda confused where to start here's the code provided we must follow

```
def go( num ):
    return 0


while ( True ):
    # enter a number
    val = int(input("Enter a number :: "))
    print( go( val ) )
```

As a beginner I'm pretty damn confused where to start.It's supposed to average the digits in a number, and this is confusing me right now.

Comment: *"You must use % for this lab to access the right most digit of the number. You will use / to chop off the right most digit."*

Comment: Look up how the % (modulus) operator works.  Look up how to use it to grab individual digits of a base-10 number.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"pretty damned confused" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: hint: `num = 1234`, `digit = num % 10` (equals 4), `num = num // 10` (equals 123). Do this in a loop until `num == 0`.

Comment: Thank you,this helped me understand how i am suppose to be using the loop and ground division correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, i followed Crytofool's method

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
count = 0
result = 0
while number:
  result, number = result + number % 10, number // 10 #grabbing induvidual digits of base 10, chopping off right most digit
  count = count +1 
print(result/count)
```